# Problem with page numbering (double page numbering)

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, arabic, page, roman-numerals

In my thesis only this page has two number i want only bottom roman number like other front pages, but i don't know why the arabic number 8 is appeared in upper right , no any other pages in the thesis has that problem.

[image: The problem]

Comment: You may provide some contents in your thesis template related to the issue, for example code about `\listoffigures` in the template `.cls` file.

Comment: Thank you @TeddyvanJerry

Comment: Without the source, I can't say much. If you're using a standard document class, a look at your preamble and frontmatter might reveal the problem. If the document class is modified or non standard, then attach that with your source too.

Comment: Also, if your document is only in English with no Arabic text/packages, you don't need the [Arabic] tag for it.